# Como actualizar nodejs en ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, linux, ubuntu

Tenia instalada la versión 8.10.0 y actualice a la versión 10.4.1 con npm:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

**Todo bien sin errores**, pero al ejecutar:

```
nodejs -v
```

en la terminal, me informa que sigo con la 8.10.0 ?

Comment: Te redirijo aquí, yo uso n me parece muy intuitivo, suerte!! https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (NVM) para manejar las versiones de node. Es mas sencillo actualizar o tener mas de una versión instalada.

Comment: Otra opción a lo que te recomendó @jonatanquintero es usar [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) que es similar a `nvm`.

Answer (score 2):

Recomiendo que mejor actualices node utilizando Node Version Manager (NVM) que es una herramienta que facilita mucho las actualizaciones, solo necesitas instalar nvm en tu ordenador, para hacerlo solo necesitas correr ejecuta los siguientes comandos Wget o cURL:

Via cURL:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

Via Wget:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

Una vez instalado, tienes que cerrar y volver a abrir el terminal para que se agregue el alias, lo siguiente a hacer es instalar node.

```
nvm install node
```

o si prefieres una version de node en especifico puedes instalarla agregando la version (puedes ver las versiones disponibles [aqui](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)):

```
nvm install node v12.6.1
```

y listo, si corres `node -v` ya deveria aparecerte la nueva version de node que has descargado

Nota: si no tienes cURL o Wgeg puedes instalarlos en ubuntu con los siguientes comandos:

Instalar cURL:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install curl
```

ver version:

```
curl --version
```

Instalar Wget:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install wget
```

ver version:

```
wget --version
```

Puedes encontrar más información [aqui](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: falto el comando nvm use

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu tiene un gran problema con las versiones de sus paquetes, ellos no suelen actualizarlos y por ende hay incongruencias con software actual de parte de sus repositorios oficiales. La cosa es que constantemente saldran nuevas versiones de Node asi que el metodo que te voy a recomendar es uno sumamente simple, yo lo uso personalmente para mis despliegues porque esta mantenido por [Nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) asi que a diferencia de otras fuentes, este metodo siempre estara funcionando. Debes elegir entre la version LTS o latest.

### Antes de empezar

Deberas desinstalar toda version previa de `nodejs` en el sistema para eso ejecuta

```bash
sudo apt purge -y nodejs npm --auto-remove
```

### Node LTS

La version LTS es la mas estable y actualizada que se ofrece, actualmente estan en la version 20.x para instalarla en Ubuntu debes ejecutar los comandos:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

### Node Latest

Si te interesa la ultima version de Node con las ultimas caracteristicas, ejecuta los siguientes comandos.

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

### Notas

- Ambos metodos ya instalan `npm` en su version mas estable.
- El paquete `curl` ya viene preinstalado en todas las versiones de
  Ubuntu asi que no deberias tener ningun problema con los comandos.
- El paquete `nodejs` obtendra nuevas actualizaciones de seguridad y parches para errores ejecutando `apt update`.
- Puedes activar `yarn` con el comando `sudo corepack enable`

### Actualizar `npm`

Si de todas maneras quieres la ultima version de `npm` ejecuta

```bash
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

Con esto podras adquirir y actualizar Node en cualquier distro Ubuntu